# SQL join two table together

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following tables:

```
table1
a     b
1     100
2     200
3     300
4     400

table2
c     b
55    100
55    200
56    300
```

I want to get the following output:

```
55    100    1
55    200    2
55    300    -
55    400    -
56    100    -
56    200    -
56    300    3
56    400    -
```

I tried the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
full JOIN table2
```

output:

```
 a    b    c    a
 1    100  55   100
 1    100  55   200
 1    100  55   100
 1    100  55   200
 2    300  56   300
 ....
```

also I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
join table2 on table1.b = table2.b 
union 
SELECT * 
FROM table2 
join table1 on table1.b = table2.b
```

the output:

```
1    100    55   100
1    200    55   200
3    300    56   300
```

Is this possible in microsoft SQL 2012? and how

Comment: I'm sure it's possible.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: yes I tried the following: SELECT * FROM table1 join table2 on table1.b = table2.b union SELECT * FROM table2 join table1 on table1.b = table2.b, but didn't work

Comment: Put that in your question, formatted properly, and explain what you mean by "didn't work".

Comment: Your question looks much better.  Thanks for taking the time to fix it up :)

Comment: Could you clarify what the logic behind your resultant table is? How do you have so many records for `56` when there is only one initially?

Comment: So what, is to get all the combinations for table2.c and table1.b, and then join this with table1 (i.e. put the a values into the result) hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure I understand your expected outcome, but it sounds like you're looking for a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

```
SELECT table1.a, COALESCE(table1.b, table2.b), table2.c
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.b = table2.b
```

This will get the fields from `table1` and, if any exist, map them to those from `table2`.

Given your example, it will return the following table.

```
A    B      C
1    100    55
2    200    55
3    300    56
4    400    (null)
```

I know that isn't the same as the expected result you gave, but this will correlate the data that actually exists.

I'm requesting clarification in a comment and will revise this as necessary.